# Dojo Dijit - Widget within a widget

Tags: dojo

- I am using OneUI which is basically just an extension of the dojo didjit widgets.

I need to put a widget inside a widget.
I am using a div with data-dojo-type="dojo.store.Memory".
I am then setting various elements of this using data-dojo-props. 
So for example I have some spans and links set within the data-dojo-props.
These are work and display fine. 
I am now trying to add a div which itself is a widget. So I've added the div and within this div I am setting the data-dojo-type as a HoverHelpToolTip and setting some other elements such as an onmouseover and some data-dojo-props.

Essentially what should happen is that a hover help tooltip should pop up on mouse over - but it isn't working at all.

So I suppose my question here is how do I correctly nest one widget within another?

Thanks

Sample Code

I am declaring it as follows...

```
<div data-dojo-id="store1819454249457680384" data-dojo-type="dojo.store.Memory"     id="store1819454249457680384" data-dojo-props="data:[{"Name":"<!--o3nv-->&nbsp;","id":1,"gender":"Female","ActionColumn":"<span class=\"actions\" ><a href=\"...\" onclick=\"...\" title=\"Click here to edit this item\" >Edit<\/a><span class=\"linksDivider\" > | <\/span><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"...\" title=\"Click here to delete this item\" >Delete<\/a><\/span>","Person.firstName":"werrwewre",

<!-- This is the start of the code in question -->

"HelpColumn":"<div class=\"hiddenHelpDialog\" data-dojo- props=\"forceFocus:true,connectId:['helpAnchor_rowHelp10309939']\" data-dojo- type=\"idx\/oneui\/HoverHelpTooltip\" id=\"rowHelp10309939\" style=\"text-align: left;  position:relative; display:none\" widgetid=\"rowHelp10309939\" ><div  class=\"helpDivDialog\" ><p class=\"helpFieldHeadingDialog\" >\u00a0<\/p><p  class=\"helpDescriptionTextDialog\" >BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH<\/p><\/div><\/div><a  class=\"openHelpLink openHelpLinkDisplayField\" id=\"helpAnchor_rowHelp10309939\"  onmouseover=\"idx.oneui.HoverHelpTooltip.defaultPosition=['above']\" ><\/a>"}]" ><!-- comment--></div>
```

It produces the following HTML which works correctly apart from the HoverHelpTip not appearing. The onmouseover is firing. Its alsmot like the widget isn't registered with dojo?!?!

```
<div widgetid="rowHelp1248193624" style="text-align: left; position:relative; display:none" id="rowHelp1248193624" data-dojo-type="idx/oneui/HoverHelpTooltip" data-dojo-props="forceFocus:true,connectId:'helpAnchor_rowHelp1248193624'" class="hiddenHelpDialog">        <div class="helpDivDialog">
<p class="helpFieldHeadingDialog">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="helpDescriptionTextDialog">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</p></div></div>
<a class="openHelpLink openHelpLinkDisplayField" id="helpAnchor_rowHelp1248193624" onmouseover="idx.oneui.HoverHelpTooltip.defaultPosition=['above'];">
<span class="hidden">&nbsp;</span></a>
```

Comment: can you provide some code ( a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would be great), which illustrates the issue? Also, it seems to me that you've done everything declaratively, which sdoesn't seem to be the ideal approach here i guess...

Comment: The HoverHelpTooltip is declared with a style of display:none, the onmouseover changes the defaultPosition. Maybe you should be setting the display to block or inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by calling parser.instantiate(node) on the DOM Node when dojo is ready.
I dont know why but for some reason the widget was not being picked up/parsed.

I check dijit.registry and there was no mention of it and a lookup using dijit.byid returned undefined.
Explicitly instantiating the node worked however.
Anyone got any idea why????